# Converting a text file into an array: segmentation fault error

Tags: c, error-handling

I am working on a problem in the C language where I have to read a file containing the weights of elephant seals, put the contents of the file into an array, and then use that array to find the average weight of the elephant seals. I'm using a version of VNC viewer with a GCC9 complier, a C/C++ Compile Run extension in VSCode, and a C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing extension in VSCode. When I try to run the code, I end up getting a segmentation fault error and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPWn6.jpg)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzzRC.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures, but as text in the question. Anyway, your array `weights` has only one element and that won't change when you read `n` -- how could it, there's no relation between these two variables. What you can do is read `n`, then declare a varable-length array `int weights[n]`. (But if you just want simple statistics like average, min and max weights, you don't need an array at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a late answer but, your array `weights` only has one element, so you're going out of bounds when you try to access an index that is greater than 1. Instead use a pointer and `malloc` it to allocate memory for the pointer after you read `n`. I suggest you look up on `malloc` to get more clarity. Also, you have some rubbish at the end of you code: `fclose;`. It should be `fclose(fp);`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *weights, n = 0, i;
    double sum = 0;

    FILE* fp = fopen("elephant_seal_data.txt", "rb");
    if (!fp)
        exit(1);
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &n);
    weights = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &weights[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += weights[i];
    printf("average is %.2f\n", sum / n);
    fclose(fp);
    free(weights); // don't forget to free the memory!
}
```